# SQL Server processing queue with multiple clients

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have thousands of items to process stored in a SQL Server table. Several clients are taking small batches from the table and mark them as dequeued. How can I ensure no item is dequeued more than once?

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use a stored procedure and a transaction.

```
create procedure my_proc @Count INT AS
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  DECLARE @TblTmp TABLE (ID BIGINT, ...)
  SELECT TOP(@Count) ID, <other columns> into @TblTmp FROM <table>
  DELETE FROM <table> WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @TmpTable)
  COMMIT
  SELECT * FROM @TmpTable
```

This procedure takes a parameter specifying the block size and uses a table variable for temporary storage, you will need to fill out @tmpTable so that it matches the columns you are going to select and it needs to contain some way to identify the rows that were selected (that is the purpose of ID in my example.).

Comment: This won't guarantee an item is only returned once. Two concurrent transactions can both do the SELECT at the same time and read the same rows.

Comment: Can someone offer a C# / LINQ sample code? Here is mine:


        `public static List<Jobs> DequeForLocalProcess(int Quantity)
        {
            // Read some Jobs
            JobsEntities db = new JobsEntities();
            List<Jobs> MyJobs = db.Jobs.Where(c => c.Status == "Ready").Take(Quantity).ToList();

            // Mark Jobs as DQd
            MyJobs.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Status = "InProcess");
            db.SaveChanges();

            return MyJobs;
        }` Sorry for the wrapped format - I couldn't figure out how to maintain the original.

Comment: Don't try and use Linq for this - read the article I linked about using the OUTPUT clause and do it in SQL